# QEMU/QMP alert when writing to memory

Tags: qemu, xilinx

I'm using QEMU to test some software for a personal project and I would like to know whenever the program is writing to memory.  The best solution I have come up with is to manually add print statements in the file responsible for writing to memory. Which this would require remaking the object for the file and building QEMU, if I'm correct.  But I came across QMP which uses JSON commands to manipulate QEMU, which has an entire list of commands, found here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Xilinx/qemu/master/qmp-commands.hx.
But after looking at that I didn't really see anything that would do what I want.  I am sort of a new programmer and am not that advanced. And was wondering if anyone had some idea how to go about this a better way.

Answer (score 1):

There historically hasn't been any support in QEMU for tracing all guest memory accesses, because there isn't any one place in QEMU where you could easily add print statements to trace them. This is because more guest memory accesses go through the "fast path", where we directly generate native host instructions which look up the host RAM address in a data structure (QEMU's TLB) and perform the load or store. It's only if this fast path doesn't find a hit in the TLB that we fall back to a slow path that's written in C.

The recent trace-events event 'tcg guest_mem_before' can be used to trace virtual memory accesses, but note that it won't tell you:

1. whether the access succeeded or faulted
2. what the data being loaded or stored was
3. the physical address that's accessed

You'll also need to rebuild QEMU to enable it (unlike most trace events which are compiled into QEMU by default and can be enabled at runtime.)

Comment: "It's only if this fast path doesn't find a hit in the TLB that we fall back to a slow path that's written in C." --- So does the event `guest_mem_before` happen also in case of a "fast path"?

Answer (score 1):

Recently (9 jun 2016) there were added powerful tracing features to mainline [QEMU](http://github.com/qemu/qemu).
Please see *qemu/docs/tracing.txt* file as manual.

There are a lot of events that could be traced, see 
*qemu/trace_events* file for list of them.

As i can understand the code, the "guest_mem_before" event is that you need to view guest memory writes.

**Details:**
There are tracing hooks placed at following functions:

- *qemu/tcg/tcg-op.c: tcg_gen_qemu_st* * All guest stores instructions tcg-generation
- *qemu/include/exec/cpu_ldst_template.h* all non-tcg memory access (fetch/translation time, helpers, devices)

Comment: Oops, I'd forgotten that tracing had made it into mainline. Couple of notes: (1) it's marked 'disable' in the trace-events so you'll need to rebuild QEMU to enable it (2) I tried that and it didn't compile. Maybe I'm doing something wrong...